# iOS Swift - Query values from date range in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an attendance app and I'm trying to display login time, logout time and break time, etc. values from a date range. For example, a user selects a date from 9/23/2017 to 9/25/2017 and the app should display the lists of login time, logout time, break time, etc. on those dates.

This is my code:

```
    databaseHandle = ref.child("admin").child(userID!).child("employees").child(self.employeeInfo!).child("attendance").queryOrdered(byChild: fromDateTimeStamp!).queryEnding(atValue: toDateTimeStamp).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let snap = item as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            let value = snap.value

            print("key: \(key), value: \(value!)")
        }

    })

    ref.removeObserver(withHandle: databaseHandle!)
```

I chose 9/23/2017 to 9/25/2017 and because there was no login and logout on 9/24/2017, this is what I got when tried to do the query:

```
    key: breakFinish, value: 12:17 PM
    key: breakStart, value: 11:55 AM
    key: currentDate, value: 9/23/2017
    key: login, value: 11:51 AM
    key: logout, value: 1:00 PM
    key: scanCount, value: 4
    key: breakFinish, value: 10:19 AM
    key: breakStart, value: 10:19 AM
    key: currentDate, value: 9/25/2017
    key: login, value: 10:18 AM
    key: logout, value: 10:21 AM
    key: scanCount, value: 4
```

Now, my question is how do I loop through the snapshot.children or access individual value to use it? Because I'm going to export this data into a csv file. So when I do that, I want it to be displayed like this:

```
    Date          Login        Break Start     Break Finish      Logout
    9/23/2017     11:51 AM     11:55 AM        11:55 AM          1:00 PM
    9/25/2017     11:51 AM     11:55 AM        11:55 AM          1:00 PM
```

I tried this but it gives an error when it can't find a value.

```
    let attendanceDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]

        if let actualAttendanceDict = attendanceDict {

            for each in actualAttendanceDict {

                let dateKey = each.key
                self.dateKeyArray += [dateKey]
                let dateLogin = each.value["currentDate"] as! String
                self.dateLoginArray += [dateLogin]
                let timeInTime =  each.value["login"] as! String
                self.loginTimeArray += [timeInTime]
                let timeOutTime = each.value["logout"] as! String
                self.logoutTimeArray += [timeOutTime]
                let breakStartTime = each.value["breakStart"] as! String
                self.breakStartTimeArray += [breakStartTime]
                let breakFinishTime =  each.value["breakFinish"] as! String
                self.breakFinishTimeArray += [breakFinishTime]



            }
        }
```

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to do the conversion to a dictionary *inside* the for loop:

```
databaseHandle = ref.child("admin").child(userID!).child("employees").child(self.employeeInfo!).child("attendance").queryOrdered(byChild: fromDateTimeStamp!).queryEnding(atValue: toDateTimeStamp).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    for item in snapshot.children {
        let snap = item as! DataSnapshot
        let dateKey = snap.key
        let attendanceDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]

        self.dateKeyArray += [dateKey]
        let dateLogin = attendanceDict["currentDate"] as! String
        self.dateLoginArray += [dateLogin]
        let timeInTime =  attendanceDict["login"] as! String
        self.loginTimeArray += [timeInTime]
        let timeOutTime = attendanceDict["logout"] as! String
        self.logoutTimeArray += [timeOutTime]
        let breakStartTime = attendanceDict["breakStart"] as! String
        self.breakStartTimeArray += [breakStartTime]
        let breakFinishTime =  attendanceDict["breakFinish"] as! String
        self.breakFinishTimeArray += [breakFinishTime]
    }

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Frank. I will try this code.

Comment: Hi Frank, I tried it and it worked. However, it stores data in array multiple times. I tried to check the dateLoginArray.count and it has 12 instead of 2. Because I query data from Sep 23 to Sep 25 and since there should only be 2 dates that have values, 23rd and 25th of Sep, because there's no value on the 24th, I should be able to get just 2 data on each of the array.

Comment: yeah, I had a typo in there that made it use the parent snapshot multiple times. Have a look at the latest update, specifically `let attendanceDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]`.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I tried it but I get an error on this line `let dateLogin = attendanceDict?["currentDate"] as! String`. The error is Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint

Comment: I just removed the for loop from the code and it worked. Thank you so much, Frank :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Frank's answer as reference, I just removed the for loop from the code and it worked.

```
    databaseHandle = ref.child("admin").child(userID!).child("employees").child(self.employeeInfo!).child("attendance").queryOrdered(byChild: fromDateTimeStamp!).queryEnding(atValue: toDateTimeStamp).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


         let attendanceDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]

         let dateLogin = attendanceDict?["currentDate"] as? String
         self.dateLoginArray += [dateLogin]
         let timeInTime =  attendanceDict?["login"] as? String
         self.loginTimeArray += [timeInTime]
         let timeOutTime = attendanceDict?["logout"] as? String
         self.logoutTimeArray += [timeOutTime]
         let breakStartTime = attendanceDict?["breakStart"] as? String
         self.breakStartTimeArray += [breakStartTime]
         let breakFinishTime =  attendanceDict?["breakFinish"] as? String
         self.breakFinishTimeArray += [breakFinishTime]

  })
```